# Set textbox MaxLength not Working

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

```
foreach (SPListItem news in items)
{


    TextBoxContents.Text = news["Contents"].ToString();
                            TextBoxContents.MaxLength = 10;


    news.update();
}
```

Setting textboxcontents to show max 10 characters is not working why?

Answer (score 1):

> This property is applicable only when the TextMode property is set to
>   TextBoxMode.SingleLine or TextBoxMode.Password.

see full description [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.maxlength.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

according to msdn:

```
// Set the maximum characters a user can manually type 
// into the TextBox.
myTextBox.MaxLength = 500;
myTextBox.MinLines = 1;

// Set the maximum number of lines the TextBox will expand to  
// accomidate text. Note: This does not constrain the amount of  
// text that can be typed. To do that, use the MaxLength property.
myTextBox.MaxLines = 5;
```

I thnk the trick is to make the textbox multiline, but dont take my word on it ;)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength.aspx

also

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797726/how-to-set-maxlength-for-multiline-textbox